# Error of populating menu items permenantly and unwantedly in each postback in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, postback

I have a problem. In order to make it understandable, I want to denote my layout. layout is as follows:

[image]

*Menu* side is implemented by *NavController*. Here is the content of the *NavController*:

```
    public class NavController : Controller
{
    private IProductRepository repository;

    public NavController(IProductRepository repo) {

        repository = repo;
    }

    [ChildActionOnly]
    public PartialViewResult Menu(string category = null)
    {
        ViewBag.SelectedCategory = category;

        //IEnumerable<string> categories = repository.Products
        //.Select(x => x.ProductCategory)
        //.Distinct()
        //.OrderBy(x => x);

        IEnumerable<string> categories = Actions.GetirTumAksiyonları();


        return PartialView(categories);
    }

}
```

At the Menu action method, some strings populated and become visible at the *Menu* side.

There are many controllers defined in my project that manipulates the *Content* of the project, and they have buttons that post back to server. Whenever I click at one of these buttons, menu strings permenantly populated. Here is my *_Layout.cs*:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
      <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
      <link href="~/Content/Site.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
      <link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
      <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
      <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
<div id="header">
    <div class="title">Lojman Bilgi Sistemi</div>
</div>
<div id="categories">
    @{ Html.RenderAction("Menu", "Nav"); }
</div>
<div id="content">
    @RenderBody()
</div>
```

How can I overcome the issue? thanks in advance.

Comment: **Whenever I click at one of these buttons, menu strings permenantly populated** ? can you specify your issue?

Comment: Dear Mohammed Dawood Ansari; In accordance with my design, some actions in my project shall appear at the *Menu* section of the page. These actions are, "Apply", "Search for my Applications" , "Find People ". These three string appears, and when user clicks on it, an action has taken evenly with the string. Then page postbacks, another three strings, namely "Apply", "Search for my Applications" and "Find People " appends at the *Menu* section, anyhow I want to see that *Menu* section static

Comment: tried something similar, everything is working fine at my end.

Answer (score 1):

```
You can write your Menu method this way. Cheers :)

[ChildActionOnly]
public PartialViewResult Menu(string category = null)
{
    // Logic

}
```

Comment: Dear Dilip N;
I have updated my source code as follows, notwithstanding I can not solve the issue. The update is depicted in my main post.